# Ensuring References are properly set for Windows Phone in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

**Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 v12... update 5, .NET v4.6...**

**New to the programming of Windows Phone in Visual Studio**

**Setup:** File > New Project > Templates > Visual Basic > Store Apps > Windows Phone Apps > Blank App (Windows Phone)

Trying to keep this simple and focused on the specific problem:

**Steps Taken:**  In the template project's MainPage.xaml the following line (attribute) was added to the opening < page > element.

```
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
```

The project was successfully built.  Then the opening element was changed  from

```
< Page > to < phone:PhoneApplicationPage >
```

**Error Messages:**

```
The name "PhoneApplicationPage" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone".
and
Unknown type 'PhoneApplicationPage' in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone'
'Sub Main' was not found in 'App1'.
'InitializeComponent' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

I listed all of the errors in case I'm misunderstanding what the build is trying to tell me.  I'm thinking the problem is a Reference and the other errors are consequences of the Reference problem.  If it is the other way around please let me know.

I have a downloaded source code phone project in C# from the book I'm studying for WPF.  It builds just fine using the < phone:PhoneApplicationPage > opening element.  I figure that means the libraries are in fact on the development PC.

I believe this to be a simple problem making sure the project references are properly set, but after trying for some time to fix it I can't figure it out.

During my research I found that certain things changed from Windows Phone 8 to Windows Phone 8.1.  The Package.appxmanifest seems to be the place to set many things previously set in XAML, but I didn't see a place to enable < phone:PhoneApplicationPage >; I presume that really needs to be taken care of by a proper Reference.

My research into the 2 projects (downloaded C# code and my VB templated code) revealed among other things a difference in the Solution Explorer References node.  In the C# project it says:

```
.NET for Windows Phone
Windows Phone
```

In the VB template code it says:

```
.NET for Windows Store apps
Windows Phone 8.1
```

When I look in Object Explorer I can find Microsoft.Phone and all its children including Microsoft.Phone.Controls which includes PhoneApplicationFrame.

So I don't understand why I can't use that Class in this basic built-in template project.

I'm familiar enough with References, but clearly not an expert.  I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was trying to use the microsoft.phone.controls library in a Windows Phone 8.1 project.  That library can evidently only be used in a Windows Phone 8 project.

To get a Windows Phone 8 project a Silverlight template can be selected which offers a choice of OS after naming and clicking OK during initial project setup.  When Windows 8 is selected the < phone:PhoneApplicationPage > opening element works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue Initially when i used VS 2013. I had to Reinstall Windows Phone 8.1 SDK. Its Time Consuming and Stupid to do so but it worked for me.

Note: Now that VS 2015 Community is available and all Installs/Tools/SDK are inbuilt, if you install VS 2015 it should be good. I'm not saying you should install VS 2015 but if you want, you can.

Comment: Do I have to uninstall anything first, or just re-install over the top of what is there?

Comment: Use Repair in Control Panel and it should take care of it.

Comment: I thought that would be it, but then Programs and Features show Visual Studio 2013 at update 3 and it is actually at update 5 which causes me to have concern about the back and forth upgrading I've done.  So I've decided to simply re-install VS 2015 at update 5 and go from there - or maybe VS2015.  I'll report back.  I actually did reload the phone 8.1 SDK update 1 and it didn't change things.